# Form wont return array when using this function to overcome magic quotes?

Tags: php, arrays, magic-quotes-gpc

To counteract magic quotes I have this function set at the top of every page.
However it seems to be affecting when I have an array in a form `<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" />`.

```
if ( in_array( strtolower( ini_get( 'magic_quotes_gpc' ) ), array( '1', 'on' ) ) ) {
    $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
    $_GET = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_GET );
    $_COOKIE = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_COOKIE );
}
```

I removed the function and it worked returning the full array when printing the array.
However I need magic quotes off and also.

With the funciton I just get `Array` returned.

How can I change the function above or overcome this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent page on the php website about [how to disable magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php), both in the `.ini` file and at runtime. I highly suggest using their code instead of something homebaked.

Comment: perfect thanks, their code works perfectly - which is obvious it's in their own documentation! - I am not able to adjust .ini but will in my next hosting environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk_recursive`:

```
function gpc_stripslashes(&$value, $key) {
    $value = stripslashes($value);
}
array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'gpc_stripslashes');
```

Or PHP 5.3 way (although magic_quotes_gpc is off by default in 5.3):

```
array_walk_recursive($_GET, function (&$value, $key) {
    $value = addslashes($value);
});
```